AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CustomActionMaskedEnvironment.observation_space' in RLlib with PettingZoo environment
I have this very basic custom parallel multi agent environment written in PettingZoo.
import functools
import random
from copy import copy

import numpy as np
from gymnasium.spaces import Discrete, MultiDiscrete

from pettingzoo import ParallelEnv


class CustomActionMaskedEnvironment(ParallelEnv):
    """The metadata holds environment constants.

    The "name" metadata allows the environment to be pretty printed.
    """

    metadata = {
        "name": "masked_parallel_env",
    }

    def __init__(self):
        """The init method takes in environment arguments.

        Should define the following attributes:
        - escape x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - timestamp
        - possible_agents

        Note: as of v1.18.1, the action_spaces and observation_spaces attributes are deprecated.
        Spaces should be defined in the action_space() and observation_space() methods.
        If these methods are not overridden, spaces will be inferred from self.observation_spaces/action_spaces, raising a warning.

        These attributes should not be changed after initialization.
        """
        self.escape_y = None
        self.escape_x = None
        self.guard_y = None
        self.guard_x = None
        self.prisoner_y = None
        self.prisoner_x = None
        self.timestep = None
        self.possible_agents = ["prisoner", "guard"]

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        """Reset set the environment to a starting point.

        It needs to initialize the following attributes:
        - agents
        - timestamp
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - escape x and y coordinates
        - observation
        - infos

        And must set up the environment so that render(), step(), and observe() can be called without issues.
        """
        self.agents = copy(self.possible_agents)
        self.timestep = 0

        self.prisoner_x = 0
        self.prisoner_y = 0

        self.guard_x = 6
        self.guard_y = 6

        self.escape_x = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.escape_y = random.randint(2, 5)

        observation = (
            self.prisoner_x + 7 * self.prisoner_y,
            self.guard_x + 7 * self.guard_y,
            self.escape_x + 7 * self.escape_y,
        )

        observations = {
            "prisoner": {
                "observation": observation,
                "action_mask": [0, 1, 1, 0]
            },
            "guard": {
                "observation": observation,
                "action_mask": [1, 0, 0, 1]
            },
        }

        # Get dummy infos. Necessary for proper parallel_to_aec conversion
        infos = {
            a: {

            } for a in self.agents
        }

        return observations, infos

    def step(self, actions):
        """Takes in an action for the current agent (specified by agent_selection).

        Needs to update:
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - terminations
        - truncations
        - rewards
        - timestamp
        - infos

        And any internal state used by observe() or render()
        """
        # Execute actions
        prisoner_action = actions["prisoner"]
        guard_action = actions["guard"]

        if prisoner_action == 0 and self.prisoner_x > 0:
            self.prisoner_x -= 1
        elif prisoner_action == 1 and self.prisoner_x < 6:
            self.prisoner_x += 1
        elif prisoner_action == 2 and self.prisoner_y > 0:
            self.prisoner_y -= 1
        elif prisoner_action == 3 and self.prisoner_y < 6:
            self.prisoner_y += 1

        if guard_action == 0 and self.guard_x > 0:
            self.guard_x -= 1
        elif guard_action == 1 and self.guard_x < 6:
            self.guard_x += 1
        elif guard_action == 2 and self.guard_y > 0:
            self.guard_y -= 1
        elif guard_action == 3 and self.guard_y < 6:
            self.guard_y += 1

        # Generate action masks
        prisoner_action_mask = np.ones(4, dtype=np.int8)
        if self.prisoner_x == 0:
            prisoner_action_mask[0] = 0  # Block left movement
        elif self.prisoner_x == 6:
            prisoner_action_mask[1] = 0  # Block right movement
        if self.prisoner_y == 0:
            prisoner_action_mask[2] = 0  # Block down movement
        elif self.prisoner_y == 6:
            prisoner_action_mask[3] = 0  # Block up movement

        guard_action_mask = np.ones(4, dtype=np.int8)
        if self.guard_x == 0:
            guard_action_mask[0] = 0
        elif self.guard_x == 6:
            guard_action_mask[1] = 0
        if self.guard_y == 0:
            guard_action_mask[2] = 0
        elif self.guard_y == 6:
            guard_action_mask[3] = 0

        # Action mask to prevent guard from going over escape cell
        if self.guard_x - 1 == self.escape_x:
            guard_action_mask[0] = 0
        elif self.guard_x + 1 == self.escape_x:
            guard_action_mask[1] = 0
        if self.guard_y - 1 == self.escape_y:
            guard_action_mask[2] = 0
        elif self.guard_y + 1 == self.escape_y:
            guard_action_mask[3] = 0

        # Check termination conditions
        terminations = {
            a: False for a in self.agents
        }

        rewards = {
            a: 0 for a in self.agents
        }

        if self.prisoner_x == self.guard_x and self.prisoner_y == self.guard_y:
            rewards = {
                "prisoner": -1,
                "guard": 1
            }

            terminations = {
                a: True for a in self.agents
            }

            self.agents = []

        elif self.prisoner_x == self.escape_x and self.prisoner_y == self.escape_y:
            rewards = {
                "prisoner": 1,
                "guard": -1
            }

            terminations = {
                a: True for a in self.agents
            }

            self.agents = []

        # Check truncation conditions (overwrites termination conditions)
        truncations = {
            "prisoner": False,
            "guard": False
        }

        if self.timestep > 100:
            rewards = {
                "prisoner": 0,
                "guard": 0
            }

            truncations = {
                "prisoner": True,
                "guard": True
            }

            self.agents = []

        self.timestep += 1

        # Get observations
        observation = (
            self.prisoner_x + 7 * self.prisoner_y,
            self.guard_x + 7 * self.guard_y,
            self.escape_x + 7 * self.escape_y,
        )

        observations = {
            "prisoner": {
                "observation": observation,
                "action_mask": prisoner_action_mask,
            },
            "guard": {
                "observation": observation,
                "action_mask": guard_action_mask
            },
        }

        # Get dummy infos (not used in this example)
        infos = {"prisoner": {}, "guard": {}}

        return observations, rewards, terminations, truncations, infos

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        """Renders the environment."""

        grid = np.zeros((7, 7), dtype = object)
        grid[self.prisoner_y, self.prisoner_x] = "P"
        grid[self.guard_y, self.guard_x] = "G"
        grid[self.escape_y, self.escape_x] = "E"
        print(f"{grid} \n")

    # Observation space should be defined here.
    # lru_cache allows observation and action spaces to be memoized, reducing clock cycles required to get each agent's space.
    # If your spaces change over time, remove this line (disable caching).
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def observation_space(self, agent):
        # gymnasium spaces are defined and documented here: https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/spaces/
        return MultiDiscrete([7 * 7 - 1] * 3)

    # Action space should be defined here.
    # If your spaces change over time, remove this line (disable caching).
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def action_space(self, agent):
        return Discrete(4)

The test function pettingzoo.test.parallel_api_test passes. Now, I would like to train with RLlib.
from ray import tune
from ray.rllib.env import ParallelPettingZooEnv
from ray.tune.registry import register_env

env_name = "mpe"

# Register the environment
def env_creator(args):
    return ParallelPettingZooEnv(CustomActionMaskedEnvironment())

register_env(env_name, env_creator)

This code, however, fails with AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CustomActionMaskedEnvironment.observation_space' on <module '__main__' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/_private/workers/default_worker.py'>:
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPO


config = {
    "env": env_name,
    "env_config": {},  # config to pass to env class
    "num_workers": 1,  # Adjust as necessary
    "framework": "torch",  # or "tf" if using TensorFlow
    "multiagent": {
        "policies": {
            "prisoner": (None, MultiDiscrete([7 * 7 - 1] * 3), Discrete(4), {}),
            "guard": (None, MultiDiscrete([7 * 7 - 1] * 3), Discrete(4), {}),
        },
        "policy_mapping_fn": lambda agent_id: agent_id,
    },
}

# Run the training
results = tune.run(PPO, config=config, stop={
    "training_iteration": 5
})

Why?
